# Why doesn't ice in a glacier feel as cold when I touch it as the ice I get from my freezer?

Tags: water, thermal-conductivity, ice, perception, heat-conduction

When I was in Iceland, I went to a tour in a glacier and I remember the ice that was there. It looked and felt like a huge amorphous block of glass: hard, smooth, ***not* wet, and *not that* cold**.

Not as cold as the cold I feel when I touch the ice cubes from my freezer.

Why is that?

I'm not expert of biology, but if feel cold when I touch an object that means

- $T_{hand} > T_{obj}$, where the temperature is measured at the surfaces which are to be put in contact
- the ratio of thermal conductivities $\frac{k_{obj}}{k_{hand}}$ must be sufficiently high to guarantee that

  - the object can sustain an inward heatflow without rising the temperature at the surface too much (otherwise it would reach equilibrium with my hand, which means I don't feel cold anymore, right?)
  - my hand can't keep up with that, as in the temperature at the tip of my finger is at the temperature of the ice, so my hand keeps losing heat through a high gradient of temperature between the bulk of my finger and the surface

Now, based on my experience, I felt less cold when I touched the ice in the glacier than when I touch the "wet" ice from my freezer.

I guess this different perception has to do with different conductivities and/or capacities of ice and water. But how?

Most importantly, **is there a dimensionless number which can express this?**

Comment: Without making any statement on the physics involved, I would imagine that when you're reaching into your freezer your hand is relatively warm (and wet) compared to when you're out in the Icelandic wilderness touching a glacier, so it seems like there would be a difference in perception even if there wasn't a significant physical difference.

Comment: That surely has an impact, but I can tell you that there was no way to get my hand wet by holding my hand on the ice of the glacier. As regards how long I could have kept my hand on it before surrendering to the cold, I can't remember exactly, unfortunately.